# CouchDB: Restricting users to only replicating their own documents

Tags: couchdb

I'm having trouble finding documentation on the request object argument used in replication filters ('req' in the sample below):

```js
function(doc, req) {
  // what is inside req???
  return false;
}
```

This [old CouchBase blog post](http://blog.couchbase.com/what%E2%80%99s-new-apache-couchdb-011-%E2%80%94-part-three-new-features-replication) has a little code snippet that shows the userCtx variable being a part of the request object:

> What is this userCtx? When you make an authenticated request against
>   CouchDB, either using HTTP basic auth, secure cookie auth or OAuth,
>   CouchDB will verify the user’s credentials. If they match a CouchDB
>   user, it populates the req.userCtx object with information about the
>   user.

This userCtx object is extremely useful for restricting replication of documents to the owner of the document. Check out this example:

```js
function(doc, req) {
  // require a valid request user that owns the current doc
  if (!req.userCtx.name) {
    throw("Unauthorized!");
  }
  if(req.userCtx.name == doc.owner) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

But the problem now is that CouchDB requires the filter method to be explicitly chosen by the initiator of the replication (in this case, the initiator is a mobile user of my web app):

```bash
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/_replicate \
-d '{"source":"database", \
     "target":"http://example.com:5984/database", \
     "filter":"example/filtername"
     }'
```

**The Question**

Is there a way to enforce a specific filter by default so that users are restricted to replicating only their own data? I'm thinking the best way to do this is to use a front end to CouchDB, like Nginx, and restrict all replication requests to ones that include that filter. Thoughts? Would love a way to do this without another layer in front of CouchDB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data replication stands right with user ability to read data. Since if your users shares data within single database all of them has right to replicate all of them to their local couches. So you couldn't apply any documents read restriction unless you've split single shared database into several personal ones - this is common use case for such situations.

There is no any way to enforce apply changes feed filter or other parameters like views has. However, you can use [rewrites](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Rewriting_urls) to wraps requests to some resources with predefined query parameters or even with dynamic ones. This is a little not solution that you'd expected, but still better that nginx and some logic at his side: probably, you'd to allow users to specify custom filters with custom query parameters and enforce you're own only if nothing specified, right?

P.S. Inside `req` object is very useful about current request. Partially it was described at [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/ExternalProcesses#JSON_Requests), but it's a little out of date. However, it's easily to view it with simple show function:

```
function(doc, req){
    return {json: req}
}
```

Comment: +1 My idea was to use nginx to restrict only replication traffic so that users can't do explicit requests on specific documents or views. I'll have to look into rewrites.

Comment: @pokstad this is simple and intuitive idea, but "buggy" since there are a lot of ways to workaround it: document API, changes feeds, views, lists, shows, rewrites - your nginx rules will be quite big and grow in time. CouchDB pattern for this problem is users personal databases that contains only those information that user able to read and, probably, might to change. Easy to set up, easy to manage, easy to keep data secured. Nginx in this case might hide this fact providing common urls for each users, but better to keep things explicit (imho).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that route. Is there a good guide to implementing a database-per-user couchdb environment?

Comment: Oh, I'd saw it in most presentations about CouchDB, but couldn't find any useful link in my bookmarks /: But it's plain simple: create database, [set up](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview#Authorization) his admins/members, push ddocs with filters that will split data to share from private one and create replication rules for [_replicator](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Replicator_database). Each user will work with his own db while if he shares data with someone it will be instantly replicated to them. Replication topology mostly depended from app logic.

Comment: For example, if your application is mailbox, probably there would be one huge database that holds all "mails" and a lot of small databases with personal users mails. This huge db will "fan out" incoming mails to users dbs and grab outgoing from them. For document exchange app p2p model would be more preferred.

Comment: I see. I'm concerned about having to write code to create databases each time a user account is created. Also, I'm concerned about configuring replication for all user databases with the large public database. Wish CouchDB handled these issues out of the box.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17714/discussion-between-kxepal-and-pokstad)